# Do you want the application “Python.app” to accept incoming network connections? after adding to keychain

Tags: mac, python, keychain

I'm running `python server.py` using bottle server

I follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688841/add-python-to-os-x-firewall-options and add `which python` and `which python3` to keychain

Everytime I run bottle server I get same box popping up. I also added `pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8080` to `/etc/pf.conf`

My bottle file is like

```
import bottle

bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH = ["static", "views"]
app = bottle.default_app()

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, reloader=True, debug=True)
```

so now anytime I update the server, when a request is made, I get the popup

How can I stop this popup? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may need the `--deep` flag... Compare the answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121010/6126 which works for me:

```bsh
# Re-signing an app: 
codesign -f --deep -s <certname> /path/to/app
# Verify that it worked: 
codesign -dvvvv /path/to/app
```

(Note that you need to accept the dialog one last time)

Comment: I upvoted as it was an important tip - but it still doesn't work on macOS Mojave ...